# CSS - Alinhar conjunto de imagens no centro de uma div

Tags: css

Preciso alinhar um conjunto de imagens randômicas no centro de uma div, segue código de exemplo:

HTML

```
<div class="divAlign">
    <img src="teste.jpg">
    <img src="teste2.jpg">
    <img src="teste3.jpg">
    <img src="teste4.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.divAlign {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.divAlign img {
    width: 60px;
}
```

Se tiver 4 imagens ou 2 ou 1 elas tem q ficar no meio, todas juntas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá!!!

Bem, para alinhar uma imagem na vertical, você pode usar vertical-align. Para alinhar à esquerda ou à direita, pode usar float. para alinhar horizontalmente no meio pode fazer o seguinte:

```css
div.img-container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

div.img-container img{
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/2etLbocu/6/)

Outro exemplo:

```css
div.img-container{
  text-align:center;
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}

div.img-container div{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:5px 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/140x100">
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/B6Jsy/)

Comment: as imagens tem q estar uma ao lado da outra e não uma em cima da outra!

Comment: Pronto, bro! Vê agora!!!

Comment: certo, vlw!!!!!!!!!